# Laravel 419 page expired when user tries to login when already logged

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have this problem on laravel: when the user tries to login on my application and he's already logged in, appears on the screen the 419 error: "Page Expired". The same thing happens when the user tries to logout and he's already logged out....

All of the forms contains the @csrf (I already changed to {{csrf_field}} but the same thing happens...)

Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: If user is already logged in, what's the need to log in again?

Comment: Yeah I know that. But in a moment I was testing the application and I forgot that i was already logged in and the login page was already opened and then the error appeared... Some of the users of my application said that this error was appearing as well

Comment: 419 is not related to the Authentication - and can happen in any forms that has been sitting for too long. Have a look at [https://gist.github.com/jrmadsen67/bd0f9ad0ef1ed6bb594e](https://gist.github.com/jrmadsen67/bd0f9ad0ef1ed6bb594e) to handed it gracefully

Comment: if the user already login you can restrict them not entering the login page, you can wirte a function to check on the login page